# gen_calibration.py: unable to read 32db.xml

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

3D lidar :   HDL-64E S3   ,     ubuntu 14.04    indigo

when I operate the lidar HDL-64E S3 as the tutorial  "http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E"     and run command  "rosrun velodyne_pointcloud gen_calibration.py 32db.xml"       ,    will appear  as the following:
converting "32db.xml" to "32db.yaml"
gen_calibration.py: unable to read 32db.xml

why ?    I have checked that there is 32db.xml in the package.

someone can help me?
thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238804/gen_calibration.py:-unable-to-read-32db.xml/) by [jiashiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26780/jiashiwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

64db.xml can be found in the file calibration in stick member.     the 64e_points.launch file can be got by just modifying 32e_points.launch

when run "rosrun velodyne_pointcloud gen_calibration.py 64db.xml"  ,  should make the command run in the 64db.xml 's dictionary.

there are also two matters should be paid attention if want to make it work:
a,  make sure "sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100"  succeed( chech it by "ifconfig -a",look at whether eth0  becomes  192.168.3.100).    There is a problem here: eth0 may not become "192.168.3.100" after "sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100",  I may do this several times（For the ifconfig issue ,  do “sudo ifdown eth0” and then after a few seconds do “sudo ifup eth0”.  After change the interface config you may have to force it to read the new config changes by shutting it down and bringing it back up ,  and then the problem can be solved）.

b,  "roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 64e_points.launch calibration:=/home/user/64db.yaml"     "user" should be user's name, my user's name is exbot.

---

Originally posted by [jiashiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26780/jiashiwei/) with karma: 36 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0